# How to find the corners of a plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a plane in Unity that has been moved, rotated and scaled differently on each axis. How do find the Vector3 coordinates of the corners of that plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object in unity has `Transform` component attached to it which has all the translation, scaling and rotation and you can apply all these transformations to any given vector with `transform.Transform<...>` methods. Default unity plane mesh has size of (10, 0, 10), so calculating its corners in world space would look like this:

```
var corner0 = plane.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(5, 0, 5));
var corner1 = plane.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(-5, 0, 5));
var corner2 = plane.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(-5, 0, -5));
var corner3 = plane.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(5, 0, -5));
```

Answer (score 4):

I would put an empty game object at each corner and make all 4 of them children of the plane. Anytime you need to find the location of the corners, add up transform.position of the plane with transform.position of the corner.

Vlad

Comment: How do I precisely place them there?

Comment: Place the corners at (5,0,5), (5,0,-5), (-5,0,-5), (-5,0,5) (relative to the plane)